# box.com api without Oauth2

Tags: box-api

I created box.com application and want to access files and folders under my account using  api sdk https://github.com/box/box-windows-sdk-v2. Is it possible to not use OAuth2 for authentication(something like
curl https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/FOLDER_ID/items?limit=2&offset=0 \
- H Authorization: client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID client_secret=MY_CLIENT_SECRET) and get access only for my data.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to go through the oauth process and get a bearer token to use the Box API.

Answer (score 0):

as user1989104 said: you won't get around the OAuth process. Check my answer on another thread for kind of a workaround to this issue:
[Best way to upload files to Box.com programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20252226/best-way-to-upload-files-to-box-com-programmatically/20351889#20351889)